# how to edit a line with an extension in one file from the data of another file in linux

Tags: linux, sed, awk, numbers, edit

Inn my text file I have the following lines.

```
input.k
```

has

```
2684717    -194.7050476      64.2345581     150.6500092       0       0
2684718    -213.1575623      62.7032242     150.6500092       0       0
*INCLUDE
$# filename
./meshes/exportneu/147.k
*END
```

and

```
mesh.k
```

has

```
100
```

I want to replace the 147.k in input.k to another number form another file which is 100 in mesh.k

Required output

```
2684717    -194.7050476      64.2345581     150.6500092       0       0
2684718    -213.1575623      62.7032242     150.6500092       0       0
*INCLUDE
$# filename
../meshes/exportneu/100.k
*END
```

I used

```
sed '/\<meshes\>/!d;=;s/.* ([^ ]\+).*/\1/;R mesh.k' input.k | 
sed 'N;N;s|\n|s/|;s|\n|/|;s|$|/|;q'  >temp.sed       
sed -i -f temp.sed input.k
```

The point is that I want to replace this 147.k to  100.k where 100 is written in another file mesh.k , like in the other file only 100 is present or it could be 3 digit anyother number.

i know it can work with searching the line with word meshes for example and the dividing with last /  and piping the data from other file but am not able to formulate the sed or awk.

regards

Comment: Please show code for what you've tried, any errors you've encountered, and what your expected output *should* be.

Comment: @CodeGnome   I used following , where mesh.k is the file with number 100 or anyother 3 digit number                                                      sed '/\<meshes\>/!d;=;s/.* \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/;R mesh.k' input.k |
sed 'N;N;s|\n|s/|;s|\n|/|;s|$|/|;q' >temp.sed
sed -i -f temp.sed input.k

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++i]=$1; next} {{sub(/[0-9]+/,a[++j]); print}}' f2 f1
```

However, please note that your substitutions from another file needs to be in the same order as your input line that needs the substitution -

```
$ cat f1
../meshes/exportneu/147.k
../secondline/exportneu/10.k

$ cat f2
100
40

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[++i]=$1; next} {{sub(/[0-9]+/,a[++j]); print}}' f2 f1
../meshes/exportneu/100.k
../secondline/exportneu/40.k
```

You can improve upon your substitution inside `awk` as per your file. This is just to get you in the right direction.

Comment: how does it know which line to be edited??  I cant see anything pointer related to meshes or exportneu/147.k  ?

Comment: @potong can you please suggest me the improvement for sed or awk?